# How to specify canonical link in app on heroku when another domain points to it

Tags: heroku, seo, canonical-link

With a domain pointing to an app on Heroku, I want to set the canonical link to the main domain, not the Heroku url, when the current url is the Heroku url, and not the domain..

How do I do that and not have the canonical link there when someone goes to the site at the main domain url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of

```
ENV['HTTP_HOST']
ENV['SERVER_NAME']
ENV['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

to check whether the site is your main server and if not, print out the canonical URL.

You can also take a look at the `ENV` variable by dumping it out for more info:

```
<%= h ENV.inspect %>
```

Comment: i actually needed request.env["HTTP_HOST"], but you got me to the answer, thanks!